# Where is the generated WAR running app using the maven tomcat:run goal?

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

Where is the generated WAR when I use the maven `tomcat:run` goal inside my Intellij to run my tomcat?

Comment: It's probably not generating a war, just pointing tomcat to the output targets

Comment: I concur with @GeoffGenz. To run as a packaged war, you need to use the [tomcat:run-war](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-war-mojo.html) goal.